# Adding parquet-avro support to scalding

Tags: hadoop, avro, cascading, scalding, parquet

How can I create a `Scalding` `Source` that will handle conversions between `avro` and `parquet`.

The solution should:

```
 1. Read from parquet format and convert to avro memory representation
 2. Write avro objects into a parquet file
```

*Note: I noticed Cascading has a module for leveraging thrift and parquet. It occurs to me that this would be a good place to start looking. I also opened a thread on [google-groups/scalding-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalding-dev/lLg2CIFnTws)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try our latest changes in this fork -
https://github.com/epishkin/scalding/tree/parquet_avro/scalding-parquet

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The projection functionality is the reason why I was looking to parquet. I'm going to use the Typed API with these sources to really have a beautiful app. Thanks so much!

Comment: We have been also working on adding the support for Predicates. I'll share that code soon. But it uses parquet-1.6.0rc2 - not a released version of parquet

Comment: That would be absolutely fantastic :)

Comment: Hey Oleksii, when do you plan to merge this into master?

Comment: @Oleksii Do you have any plans to have a Merge request to the scalding project?